# Testing rails controller with rspec got stuck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

This is my controller

```
def log_in
    admin=Admin.find_by_name(params[:name])
    unless admin.nil?
        admin=admin.authenticate(params[:password])
        if admin==false
            # wrong password,login again
            # redirect_to sign_in_admins_url
        else
            session[:admin]=admin.name
            redirect_to root_path
        end
    end
end
```

And This is the rspec code:

```
describe "Post request for admins" do
    it "should log_in with right name and password" do
        post :log_in,name:"ryan",password:"123456"
        controller.params[:name].should=="ryan"
        controller.params[:password].should=="123456"
        session[:admin].should eq "ryan"
    end
end
```

And I the assertion always returned

`expected 'ryan',got nil`

Why did this happen? I'm still new for rspec... follow the tutorials, think it should work

Comment: are you certain you're getting into the else block? put a puts statement in there and see if you're getting where you expect. puts statements will print out to stdout on the test runner.

Comment: In what line do you get that error? Assertion of param or session?

Comment: @sugartea the session assersion.

Comment: @JedSchneider ohh.. yea,it didn't get into the else block.. and I've been told that database will be cleaned before each case running. does it mean I have to build a sample data in the rspec test script before I run the case above?

Comment: @RyanZhu you'll typically setup and fixture data in your before block.